# How to use zfill to make length equivalent to 2 digit length of n

Tags: python

I have asked a previously one question where I was impressed with unpacking approach shared by one person
I am bit playing with bit to print patterns

I want to pad the single digit with zero to make it equivalent to 2 digit number length

I tried zfill but not throwing me error : `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'zfill'`

**Code :**

```
n=15
for i in range(1,n+1):
  print(*range(1,n+1))
  n = n -1
```

**Expected output :**

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
01 02 03 04 05 06 07
01 02 03 04 05 06
01 02 03 04 05
01 02 03 04
01 02 03
01 02
01
```

Comment: For `zfill`, you would need to do `print(*str(j).zfill(2) for j in range(1,n+1))`

Comment: [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) only exists for strings: `str(value).zfill(2)`.

Comment: @c Alternatively, `print(*map(lambda x: str(x+1).zfill(2),range(n)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) `02`.

change the line : `print(*range(1,n+1))` to `print(*(f"{i:02}" for i in range(1, n + 1)))`

Full code:

```py
n = 15
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(*(f"{i:02}" for i in range(1, n + 1)))
    n = n - 1
```

output:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
01 02 03 04 05 06 07
01 02 03 04 05 06
01 02 03 04 05
01 02 03 04
01 02 03
01 02
01
```

Another option is to use `zfill` like :

```py
print(*(str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1, n + 1)))
```

you need to convert the `i` into str because `zfill` is a method of string objects.

Comment: can show me how to make use of zfill option in this

Comment: @coreke2042 `print(*(str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1, n + 1)))` I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one of them:

```
n = 15

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(' '.join(f'{j:02d}' for j in range(1, n-i+2)))
```